# Inconsistent UISearchBar sizing before first use?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

For a reason that is unclear, my UISearchBar resizes itself to a different size after the first search. There is nothing special about this search bar. It's based off of the example on the Apple IOS Library and uses a searchDisplayController, with virtually no customization.

Before:

[image: before search]

After:

[image: after search]

How can I set the size to what it is in the second screenshot when the view loads?

Comment: A small sample project that demonstrates the issue would make this much easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a nib, you can just check "Shows Cancel Button" from the Search bar options in your attributes.

If you're doing it programmatically, do some subclassing with the UISearchBar and override this method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
}
```